# Запрос sql не могу составить

Tags: sql

Не могу составить запрос на [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new):

Вывести (одним запросом) количество пользователей, задавших менее 10 вопросов, количество пользователей, задавших от 10 до 20 вопросов и количество пользователей, задавших более 20 вопросов.

Вопрос - это когда `PostTypeId=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(case when c < 10 then 1 else 0 end) L10, 
       sum(case when c >= 10 and c < 20 then 1 else 0 end) L20,
       sum(case when c >= 20 then 1 else 0 end) G20 
    from (
        select OwnerUserId, count(*) c 
           from posts 
           where PostTypeId=1 
           group by OwnerUserId
         ) t1
```